# Erro em função C# para incrementar variável

Tags: c#

Galera, sou novo e tenho algumas dúvidas "básicas".

Estou fazendo um contador de pontos, por serem muitos jogadores quero criar a função decrementar/incrementar.

### Função incrementa

```
    public void incremento(int pt, int mago)
    {
        pt++;
        switch (mago) { 
            case 1:
                labelM1.Text = String.Format("{0} Pontos", pt);
                break;

        }
     }
```

### Evento botão +(incrementar)

```
 private void M1mais_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        incremento(pt1, mago1);
    }
```

Porém na label em que deveria aparecer o total atual de pontos só incrementa a primeira vez.

O que há de errado? Essa é a melhor forma?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sua função de incremento realiza o incremento mas o valor da variável se perde. O ideal seria sua função incremento alterar o valor da variável `pt`.

Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
public void incremento(ref int pt, int mago)
{
    pt++;
    switch (mago) { 
        case 1:
            labelM1.Text = String.Format("{0} Pontos", pt);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Como o valor é lido dentro do método, deveria ser `ref` ao invés de `out`.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Obrigado! Já corrigi.

Answer (score 3):

O problema principal é você não estar fazendo uso da Orientação a Objeto. Mas vamos por partes.

### Solução 1

Você está passando uma variável de Tipo por valor como parâmetro. 
Você está usando um *int*. Um *int* é um [tipo de valor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s1ax56ch.aspx). Quando você passa um tipo de valor como argumento de uma função, essa recebe apenas uma CÓPIA da sua variável, e não sua variável. Ou seja: ele arruma o valor na função mas você não enxerga a alteração fora dela.

Para resolver isso, você deve usar o modificador ref, como citado pelo @Cigano ali. Isso vai fazer com que o parâmetro seja passado por referência. O seu método vai atuar sobre a sua variável (mesmo endereço de memória) e não mais sobre uma cópia da mesma. Mas tem que ser tanto na definição do método quanto na chamada do mesmo.

Você não costuma perceber esse erro com variáveis do Tipo de referência - resumidamente tudo que não é Tipo de valor (todos tipos de *Int* e *Float*, *decimal* e *structs*) - porque na prática é como se o objeto sendo passada como referência.

### Solução 2

Refatorar. Eu diria que, apesar do código compilar e funcionar, a lógica geral está essencialmente equivocada, do ponto de vista da orientação a objeto.

Na minha opinião você deveria estar passando um objeto do tipo Mago como argumento e não dois int. Pode parecer besteira agora, mas é melhor começar da maneira correta.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que como o parâmetro `pt` se torna uma cópia de `pt1` no momento em que você chama o método `incremento`, somente o valor de `pt` (dentro do método) é modificado, enquanto o de `pt1` (fora) permanece o mesmo.

Uma alternativa seria separar os valores da sua label em dois: um depois (correspondendo ao texto "Pontos") e outro antes do espaço (' ') em branco (correspondendo ao número), usando o método [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
private void M1mais_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pt1 = int.Parse(labelM1.Text.Split(' ')[0]); // [0] se refere ao primeiro índice do array de strings gerado, ou seja, ao número.
    incremento(pt1, mago1);
}
```